# cpp RapidJSON - Resolve key conflicts without information loss

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to parse a text file which is similar to JSON. After some character conversions, it still has some objects, which have key conflicts. So my JSON looked like this:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "a": "asdf",
        "a": "foo",
        "a": "bar",
        "a": "fdas"
    }
}
```

And i wanted to resolve it into this:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "a": [
            "asdf",
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "fdas"
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to achieve this with JsonCpp, but it can't handle the key conflicts. So i chose to use RapidJSON, especially because it CAN keep all the key-conflict-members when parsing.

To then resolve the key conflicts without loosing information, i wrote the following recursive RapidJSON cpp code:

```
void resolveKeyConflicts(rj::Value& value) {
    if (value.IsObject()) {
        std::map<std::string, unsigned int> nameCount;
        for (rj::Value::MemberIterator vMIt = value.MemberBegin();
                vMIt != value.MemberEnd(); vMIt++) {
            std::string name(vMIt->name.GetString());
            if (nameCount.find(name) == nameCount.end()) {
                nameCount[name] = 1;
            } else {
                nameCount[name] += 1;
            }
        }

        for (std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator nCIt =
                nameCount.begin(); nCIt != nameCount.end(); nCIt++) {
            if (nCIt->second > 1) {
                rj::Value newArray(rj::kArrayType);
                for (rj::Value::MemberIterator vFMIt = value.FindMember(
                        nCIt->first.c_str()); vFMIt != value.MemberEnd();
                        vFMIt++) {
                    if (vFMIt->name.GetString() == nCIt->first) {
                        rj::Value value(vFMIt->value, this->GetAllocator());
                        newArray.PushBack(value, this->GetAllocator());
                    }
                }

                value.EraseMember(value.FindMember(nCIt->first.c_str()),
                        value.MemberEnd());
                rj::Value key(nCIt->first.c_str(), nCIt->first.length(),
                        this->GetAllocator());
                value.AddMember(key, newArray, this->GetAllocator());
            }
        }

        for (rj::Value::MemberIterator vMIt = value.MemberBegin();
                vMIt != value.MemberEnd(); vMIt++) {
            if (vMIt->value.IsObject() || vMIt->value.IsArray()) {
                resolveKeyConflicts(vMIt->value);
            }
        }
    } else if (value.IsArray()) {
        for (rj::Value::ValueIterator vVIt = value.Begin(); vVIt != value.End();
                vVIt++) {
            resolveKeyConflicts(*vVIt);
        }
    }
}
```

This works pretty good as long as the conflicting key-members are the only members in that object. This can, i think, be archived with simpler code, but i additionally tried to be able to resolve arbitrary key conflicts like this:

```
{
    "key2": {
        "a": "asdf",
        "b": "foo",
        "b": "bar",
        "c": "fdas"
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
{
    "key2": {
        "a": "asdf",
        "b": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ],
        "c": "fdas"
    }
}
```

Turns out `FindMember` does not, as i thought, gives back an iterator over all members with the same key name, but just the position of the first member with that key. I think my python way of thinking may have messed with my expectations on `FindMember`. So like this, the code is going to lose the `"c": "fdas"` member.

I relied on `MemberIterator EraseMember(MemberIterator first, MemberIterator last)` because all of the other methods to remove a member mentioned in http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#ModifyObject seem to have problems removing the last member in the `key1` case. But `EraseMember` like this is definitely the wrong choice for the `key2` case.

So I'm kind of lost here. Can please somebody point me into the right direction to resolve the key conflicts without information loss, which can handle both the `key1` and the `key2` case?

edit: I'm using RapidJSON from https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/tree/v1.0.2 which is at the `v1.0.2` tag.

Comment: Duplicate keys aren't valid JSON.

Comment: @DavidHammen In ECMA-404, "An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs.
A name is a string. A single colon token follows each name, separating the name from the value. A single comma token separates a value from a following name. "  There is no constraint on duplicated names.

Comment: @DavidHammen In RFC 7159 , "The names within an object SHOULD be unique". It is not a MUST. Some programs able to handle them but some may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tricky part is to memorize whether the key has already expanded to an array (because the value may be originally an array).

So, another way is firstly convert all `key: value` into `key:[value]`, do the merge, and then convert back to `key: value` if there is only one element in the array.

This is my attempt:

```
static void MergeDuplicateKey(Value& v, Value::AllocatorType& a) {
    if (v.IsObject()) {
        // Convert all key:value into key:[value]
        for (Value::MemberIterator itr = v.MemberBegin(); itr != v.MemberEnd(); ++itr)
            itr->value = Value(kArrayType).Move().PushBack(itr->value, a);

        // Merge arrays if key is duplicated
        for (Value::MemberIterator itr = v.MemberBegin(); itr != v.MemberEnd();) {
            Value::MemberIterator itr2 = v.FindMember(itr->name);
            if (itr != itr2) {
                itr2->value.PushBack(itr->value[0], a);
                itr = v.EraseMember(itr);
            }
            else
                ++itr;
        }

        // Convert key:[values] back to key:value if there is only one value
        for (Value::MemberIterator itr = v.MemberBegin(); itr != v.MemberEnd(); ++itr) {
            if (itr->value.Size() == 1)
                itr->value = itr->value[0];
            MergeDuplicateKey(itr->value, a); // Recursion on the value
        }
    }
    else if (v.IsArray())
        for (Value::ValueIterator itr = v.Begin(); itr != v.End(); ++itr)
            MergeDuplicateKey(*itr, a);
}
```

I tested it in [this commit](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/commit/c828037784278037422198f4d0c8cac4399e2c59).

Comment: In my answer i use `resolvedConflicts` for memorizing the resolved conflicts.

As far as I can tell, your attempt is always in `O(3n)` or worse depending on `FindMember`. I think due to the nice `Swap` function, my attempt is best case in `O(2n)` and worst case in `O(3n)` depending on `std::find`. Am I mistaken?

But now i understand way better how `EraseMember` works.

Comment: My solution does not need to memorize the resolved keys, so itcan prevent memory and performance overhead for that. Since assignment is move semantic, Swap does not have superior advantage here. For runtime complexity, when not considering recursion, the complexity is O(n^2) due to linear search.

Answer (score 0):

I completely rewrote that part, trying (again) another approach. I think i found a pretty elegant solution:

```
void resolveKeyConflicts(rj::Value& value) {
    if (value.IsObject()) {
        std::vector<std::string> resolvedConflicts;
        rj::Value newValue(rj::kObjectType);
        for (rj::Value::MemberIterator vMIt = value.MemberBegin();
                vMIt != value.MemberEnd(); vMIt++) {
            rj::Value::MemberIterator nVFMIt = newValue.FindMember(vMIt->name);
            if (nVFMIt == newValue.MemberEnd()) {
                rj::Value newKey(vMIt->name, this->GetAllocator());
                newValue.AddMember(newKey, vMIt->value, this->GetAllocator());
            } else {
                std::string conflict(vMIt->name.GetString(),
                        vMIt->name.GetStringLength());
                if (std::find(resolvedConflicts.begin(),
                        resolvedConflicts.end(), conflict)
                        == resolvedConflicts.end()) {
                    rj::Value newArray(rj::kArrayType);
                    nVFMIt->value.Swap(newArray);
                    nVFMIt->value.PushBack(newArray, this->GetAllocator());
                    nVFMIt->value.PushBack(vMIt->value, this->GetAllocator());

                    resolvedConflicts.push_back(conflict);
                } else {
                    nVFMIt->value.PushBack(vMIt->value, this->GetAllocator());
                }
            }
        }

        value.SetNull().SetObject();
        for (rj::Value::MemberIterator nVMIt = newValue.MemberBegin();
                nVMIt != newValue.MemberEnd(); nVMIt++) {
            if (nVMIt->value.IsObject() || nVMIt->value.IsArray()) {
                this->resolveKeyConflicts(nVMIt->value);
            }
            value.AddMember(nVMIt->name, nVMIt->value, this->GetAllocator());
        }
    } else if (value.IsArray()) {
        for (rj::Value::ValueIterator vVIt = value.Begin(); vVIt != value.End();
                vVIt++) {
            if (vVIt->IsObject() || vVIt->IsArray()) {
                this->resolveKeyConflicts(*vVIt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not so sure about the `value.SetNull().SetObject()` part for emptying `value`, but it works.

If you think there is room for improvement, just let me know where. Thanks.